# How to come up with a suitable table design?

Tags: database-design

I have a question shown below:

```
1.Are you a good boy ? 
  ans:Yes/No
 OR,Are you a good girl?
  ans:Yes/No
 Or,Are you a good father?
  ans:Yes/No
```

If answer is `Yes to either of the three questions above then ask

```
  1.1 What is your age?ans:textbox
      OR
      What is your birth date?ans:textbox

   1.1.1 Where were you born?ans:textbox //this is the question inside the sub-question
```

Now In question (1) there are actually 3 questions but all of their id is 1....and (1.1) is the subquestion of the question number (1) which actually consists of two questions both having the same id (here it may be any number not necessarily be 1.1).

1.1.1 is the question inside the sub-question.

Now how do I create a table in sql server with all the data above so answering the above questions would appropriately insert into the tables.If the solution be normalized rather then de-normalized it would be much appreciated.

If the answer's table be shown with all the options to insert like Yes/No,Descriptive answers it would further be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the table is question. Have a type column there. Say for main question u insert 1 and for branch u insert 2. And they can't have same id if u r talking of primary key. U can do one thing that is display the items from table as u need. The fields might be this. 
1. Id,
2. Type,
3. Question. And rest your wish

Comment: thank you Dev for your prompt reply.However this doesnot solve my problem because the problem is not about main and branch.Its about the  questions in OR.for e.g the above 3 questions numbered 1.All must have the same id i.e with your reference they must get id of 1 which violates the pk constraint.similarly there is a OR in the subquestion too which too must get the same id.Have I made clear my explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly confusing and I am not sure about your current schema but if the questions are predefined from a set values, this schema is the one to go with.

```
Questions
=================
questionID
optionID
subID            (0 if not a subquestion)
Question
Composite Primary Key (questionID, subID)

Answers
=================
userID
questionID
optionID
subID
answer
Composite Primary Key (questionID, subID)
```

another approach can be..

```
Questions
===============
questionID      //Unique question ID
questionRank    //On which question number it is available i.e. 1 for "Are you a good..."
subCategory     //0 if main question, sub ID number if a sub question
question        //Actual question

UserAnswers
===============
userID
questionID
answer
```

Comment: thanks Bhrugesh at least I have an idea on how to approach this issue.

Comment: Bhrugesh what if the sub-question has a sub-question inside?

Comment: Instead of subcategory number, use subQuestionID... so basically store like a normal question with a unique questionID but its subQuestionID is the unique questionID of the parent question...simple as that.. i.e. questionID of question 1.1 is 15 then question 1.1.1 has questionID 16, questionRank 1 (because its first), subQuestionID 15 (because its parent question 1.1 has ID 15) and question is the real question

Comment: thank you Bhrugesh I now go with your approach for preparing the Questions table.However another thing I am stuck is in the answer table where previously I had just Yes/No questions which resulted in answer of just 1 for Yes and 2 for No(it was a column named answerId datatype int).Now I have to include the textbox answer aswell.If you could help me design the flexible answer table it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the questions and answers as [Bhrugesh Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986880/how-to-come-up-with-a-suitable-table-design/13992165#13992165) suggested.

In order to model which questions should follow which other questions, you need a [state transition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table).

> A state transition table is a table showing what state (or states in the case of a nondeterministic finite automaton) a finite semiautomaton or finite state machine will move to, based on the current state and other inputs.